# Fetch API - get custom response header not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, promise, fetch-api

I'm unable to get **x-Token-Expired** header in client-side in fetch request. I have added the header from server-side

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-Token-Expired", "true");
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
```

In client-side, looping through the headers , I am not able to get x-Token-Expired header.

```
 let tokenExpiredHeader = response.headers.get('x-Token-Expired');
 for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
 }
```

This is what I get in console

[image: This is what I get in log]

Although the above said header is present in response header list
[image: Network]

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you doing this cross origin? Cors can block that

Comment: @DanielA.White sir, I am requesting URL in same server (http://localhost:55555/) .